# How to show data from multiple models on the same page with active admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I am using active admin gem. In my database there are two tables: `lists` and `items`. I added the model `lists` to active admin.
My goal is when I use the basic actions (new, show, update), I should be able immediately work with the data list and it's items on one page. Can someone explain how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Active admin has a super version of the methods you want to intercept in which case you can define them and then call their parent and in the block you have access to the instance variable already created for you and you can use to perform operations on it and associate records.

```
ActiveAdmin.register List do
  controller do
    def create
      create! do |format|
        @list
      end
    end

    update
      update! do |format|
        @list
      end
    end

    def edit
      edit!
    end
  end
end
```

Hope this leads you in the right direction.